# Django REST framework: AttributeError: Serializer object has no attribute 'Meta'

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, attributeerror

Given the following model and serializer for a [Django REST framework](http://www.django-rest-framework.org) setup:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from django.db import models

class StationReport(models.Model):

    water_level = models.IntegerField(max_length=5, blank=False)
    user_name = models.CharField(max_length=256, blank=False)
    email_address = models.CharField(max_length=256, blank=True)
    recorded_at = models.DateTimeField(blank=False)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    modified_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

...

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from rest_framework import serializers
from models import StationReport

class StationReportSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    water_level = serializers.IntegerField(required=True)
    user_name = serializers.CharField(required=True)
    email_address = serializers.CharField(required=False)
    recorded_at = serializers.DateTimeField(required=True)

    def create(self, validated_data):
        return StationReport.objects.create(**validated_data)

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        instance.water_level = validated_data.get('water_level', instance.water_level)
        instance.user_name = validated_data.get('user_name', instance.user_name)
        instance.email_address = validated_data.get('email_address', instance.email_address)
        instance.recorded_at = validated_data.get('recorded_at', instance.recorded_at)
        instance.save()
        return instance
```

Why am I receiving this `AttributeError` when I visit `http://localhost:8000/stationreports/`?

```
AttributeError at /stationreports/

'StationReportSerializer' object has no attribute 'Meta'

Request Method:     GET
Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/stationreports/
Django Version:     1.7.3
Exception Type:     AttributeError
Exception Value:    

'StationReportSerializer' object has no attribute 'Meta'
```

I followed the first part of the [*Serializers* tutorial](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/1-serialization/) which does not seem to work in the presented form. I already tried to remove the `Meta` class in the model but still the error occurs.

## The problem reason

For some reason I did not exactly follow the mentioned *Serializers* tutorial. My given example works when I change the following:

### Before:

```
class GaugeReportSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    water_level = serializers.IntegerField(required=True, max_length=5)
```

### After:

```
class GaugeReportSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    water_level = serializers.IntegerField(required=True)
```

I think this mistake happened because I did the [*Quickstart* tutorial](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/quickstart/) before.

Comment: It says it all, where is your `class Meta` inside your serializer?

Comment: I can also attest to this, I changed serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer to serializers.Serializer and it worked

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Because you don't have a `Meta` class defined.

In Django REST Framework, `Meta` classes are not inherited from their parent classes.

```
class StationReportSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = StationReport
```

The above should solve your problem.

http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#inheritance-of-the-meta-class

Comment: I had Meta defined, but `model` was the wrong class. I had switched the model being serialized but failed to update the Meta.

Answer (score 7):

`HyperlinkedModelSerializer` is a model serializer. So you need to define the `class Meta` like below:

Moreover, when you set the `model` on meta class, then you don't need to explicitly define all of the fields on serializer. You just add them to the `fields` of meta class. Unless your are doing something specialized on the fields.

```
class StationReportSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):

    # ...

    class Meta:
        model = StationReport
        fields = ( 
            'water_level',
            'user_name',
            'email_address',
            'recorded_at',
        )

    extra_kwargs = {
        'water_level': {'required': True},
        'user_name': {'required': True},
        'email_address': {'required': False},
        'recorded_at': {'required': True},
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Though, I grant the answer to *mattm* because I like the **simplification approach**. Since I am a Django newbie please correct me if I made the wrong decision.

Comment: @JJD, It's OK. We answered the same thing but I just added that the purpose of using `ModelSerializer` is to avoid re-declaring all of the model fields in serializer. That's what it is for but choices are yours.